# Powershell to run task sequence from software center

Tags: powershell, task, sequence

I have Windows OS image advertised in software center which I can manually hit install that reimages the system and does other configuration afterwards. I would like to automate the execution using Powershell. I am able to do do for other advertised software like notepad++, chrome, and software updates but not to OS image. Is there any way automate it at the client side using Powershell or any other script? I do not have SCCM access to push the task sequence.
Thank you

Comment: First thing, we have sccm module for PS. But for that you need to have SCCM. I am not sure what actually your concern is.

Comment: @RanadipDutta The SCCM module is for the SCCM server environment, which he doesn't have access to. LandOfCake, what you have tried? I'm at home now and can't verify it, but UIResource COM-object should work. Ex. https://www.sepago.com/blog/2013/09/06/how-to-execute-configmgr-2012-task-sequence-from-powershell  . Ask your SCCM admin before running this. The deployment is made optional for a reason. What if someone hasn't saved their work?

Comment: My use case is little different than usual: I have automated test execution which depends on successful build. Then I have to reimage around 20 servers with server 2012 r2 std and 20 clients with with dowsing 10 os. I currently do this by selecting task sequence manually from software center. But, it is wasting a lot of my time and preventing to run my tests in fully automated faison. The task sequence to deploy OS, and other configurations are available in the software center but not able to execute it programitacilly. Nobody else is using any of these system but me.

Comment: @LandOfCake: Please accept/upvote the answer if it helps you

Comment: @Frode F. Thank you for pointing to the resource. I will try to follow that and see how far I get

Comment: @RanadipDutta What answer?

Comment: As described by David O'Brien  at link provided by @Frode F. the solution is to use package ID to execute OSD task sequence. Thank you so much. Here is an example: $UI = New-Object -ComObject "UIResource.UIResourceMgr"
 
$ProgramID = "*"
$PackageID = "%PutInYourPackageID%"
$UI.ExecuteProgram($ProgramID, $PackageID, $true)

Comment: @LandOfCake: Sorry I forgot to answer about the COM object  . Lolz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `UIResourceMgr` COM-object. Example ([source](https://www.sepago.com/blog/2013/09/06/how-to-execute-configmgr-2012-task-sequence-from-powershell)):

```
$UI = New-Object -ComObject "UIResource.UIResourceMgr"
 
$ProgramID = "*"
$PackageID = "PACKAGEID"
 
$UI.ExecuteProgram($ProgramID, $PackageID, $true)
```