# Powershell assigning a Certificate

Tags: certificate

I have certificate in the certmgr and which I am able to pull it also using :

```
$a=Get-ChildItem –Path cert:\CurrentUser\my –codeSigningCert
```

Now how can I assign the same code signature certificate to make all my scripts digitally signed? 
is there any direct way to achieve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646811/powershell-to-run-task-sequence-from-software-center#comment70560786_41646811 :)

Comment: @PrageethSaravanan: The problem has been resolved by directly getting digitally signed script externally. We do not have to assign it. Although Set-AuthenticodeSignature will do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` cmdlet:

```
$Cert = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath "C:\Test\Mysign.pfx"
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath "ServerProps.ps1" -Certificate $Cert
```

or

```
Set-AuthenticodeSignature c:\foo.ps1 @(Get-ChildItem cert:\CurrentUser\My -codesign)[0]
```

Refer to [the MS link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.security/Set-AuthenticodeSignature) or [this link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SigningPowerShellScripts.aspx) if you want more information.